# Automatically update subdomain website code on main domain changes

Tags: subdomain, shopify

We have a website - let's call it mywebsite.com - and we are adding a subdomain website - let's call it au.mywebsite.com.

The 2 websites will be identical in terms of design (HTML, CSS, JS etc.).
If I make changes to the design of the main website - mywebsite.com - is there a way to automatically push the changes to the subdomain website?

The website in question is a Shopify eCommerce website.

Comment: This would greatly benefit from sharing some details about how your site is set up. Are you using a single Shopify account or two different accounts?  If you're running two subdomains off the same Shopify account, then they would be sharing everything. If you're running two separate Shopify stores, then you would need to create a tool to sync the two stores, probably by using Shopify's theme API

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no such way you can update 2 websites simultaneously. I hope Shopify develops a webhook to inform file changes in the future.  You can do the following to achieve your requirement:

1. Make your changes to your main website.
2. Write a script to pull all the assets from your main website
3. Update all the assets in your subdomain website

Assets API Documentation - [Link](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/online-store/asset)

Alternatively, there is also a solution present for your problem at Shopify University. The solution tells you how to compare files and push data to another website. You can check it out [here](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/webhook-theme-update-doesn-t-fire-on-theme-edit-488715).